# Power Management governor changes alone from powersave to performance

Tags: 18.04, power-management, cpu, overheating, tlp

So, I'm having some overheating problems with an HP Envy 15 that are driving me nuts. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034052/ubuntu-18-04-high-cpu-fan-crazy-basic-usage) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1295374/ubuntu-16-04-hp-envy-15-high-temperature-never-below-60) for reference.

Anyway, I did an Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install. Also installed `tlp` and `cpufrequtils`. So, if I do `tlp stat -p` ...

```
+++ Processor
CPU model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz

[....]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  3100000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  3100000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  25 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  50 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  24
```

Now, since I want to use a `powersave` governor, as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/936488/424375), I get to use it.

```
+++ Processor
CPU model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz

[....]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  3100000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  3100000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  25 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  50 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  24
```

So far, so good.

Two things do call my attention:

1. If I do start using my laptopt again, don't know why, but from time to time, the `tlp stat -p` shows again that the `scaling_governor=performance`.
2. Why are `scaling_min_freq` and `scaling_max_freq` equal? I'd like to     reduce both of them to see if I can somehow control the overheating problem  that I'm facing.

How can I avoid the `performance` governor? How can I tune the `min` and `max` scaling?

thanks!

Lucas

Comment: Uninstall `cpufrequtils` If you really need it you can install it again. I suspect it is the culprit.

Comment: But I need `cpufrequtils` to set the `powersave` governor. If I uninstall it, how do I change the governor then?

Comment: `powersave` is the default governor. You have to force `performance` on. I suspect `cpufrequtils` is forcing it on. It is also probably responsible for setting `min` equal to `max`.

Comment: Ok, I've done an `apt purge cpufrequtils`, rebooted the laptop and after a `tlp stat -p` I get to see `performance` again: no changes at all. Doing a `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` shows `performance`, so it's something else doing the dirty job ... :-(

Comment: Did you change anything in `tlp` configuration file?

Comment: No ... it's a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04. Don't even know where the config file for `tlp` is. Indeed, after your comment I was looking for it to see if there is something in there ...

Comment: Well I've been using `tlp` for years and my laptop has always been at `powersave`. I haven't used `cpufrequtils` but I guess you can reinstall it if it wasn't the culprit. Hopefully someone else has experienced the same anomaly and will comment/answer.

Comment: After boot the CPU frequency scaling governor will be set to `performance` for 1 minute, then it will change to `powersave`. Is it possible you have been looking too soon after boot?

Answer (score 3):

### Force to `powersave` speed governor

You are using `sudo tlp stat -p` to find out when the speed governor is set at `performance` mode. When this happens reset it to `powersave` with this command:

```
$ echo "powersave" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

Run `tlp` statistics again and ensure minimum frequency is normalized and no longer set at maximum frequency.

Keep running `tlp` to find out how often the governor is being reset to `performance` mode.

Keep searching for the program that is reseting the speed governor.

As a last resort you could:

1. Setup a sleeping procedure to reset to `powersave` every x seconds.
2. Setup a procedure that monitors the speed governor every second and reset it when it changes.

Comment: So, after your comment on the previous comments, I dug into the config file for `tlp` in `/etc/default/tlp` and touched some parameters. The result: now overheating has lowered a lot (a lot!) and coolers are not spinning as much as before. However, from time to time, something is reverting this configuration (`powersave -> performance`) and I cannot find how to change the minimum frequency. I'll post an answer showing the parameters that I've changed in tlp.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for your second question:

> Why are scaling_min_freq and scaling_max_freq equal? I'd like to
>   reduce both of them to see if I can somehow control the overheating
>   problem that I'm facing.

I don't know how they got set to the same, but something must have done it. To limit your maximum CPU frequency, when using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, one way is (to 70% for example):

```
$ echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
```

Example:

```
doug@s15:~/temp$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:42
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:23
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:18
doug@s15:~/temp$ echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
70
doug@s15:~/temp$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:70
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:42
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:23
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:18
```